# A table of counts of http status by URL

Tags: splunk

How would I create a Splunk query to show me table of the counts of http status codes per URL?
Assuming each event contains a key of URL with a value, and key of http response code. Thanks!

```
     200    401   500
url1  6      1     1 
url2  19     2     3
```

EDIT:
Here's what I've tried so far... `index=myindex method="GET" | stats count by url, httpstatus`

Which gives me (unexpectedly) one row for each URL and HTTP Status with `[URL, httpstatus, count of occurrences of httpstatus]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What results did you get?

Comment: I'm a complete novice, so here's what I've tried so far...

index=myindex  method="GET" |  stats count by url, httpstatus    ------- 

Which gives me (unexpectedly) one row for each URL and HTTP Status with [URL, httpstatus, count of occurrences of httpstatus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `by` clause of the `stats` command specifies how you want the results grouped.  The fields in that clause will be the first columns of the results table with the remaining columns being the specified functions (count, in this case).

To get the desired output, try the `chart` command.  The `over` clause specifies the horizontal fields and the `by` clause the vertical.

```
index=myindex method="GET"
| chart count over status by URL
```

Comment: Excellent @RichG - 'chart' was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.